# Bounds or value of expectation of $\mathrm{sech}(a X)$ where $X$ is Gaussian?

Tags: integration, normal-distribution, expected-value, upper-lower-bounds, hyperbolic-functions

I would like to compute the following integral
$$
f(a) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathrm{sech}(ax)~e^{-x^2/2} \, dx, 
\quad a > 0.
$$
It is the expectation of $\mathrm{sech}(aX)$ where $X \sim N(0, 1)$.

One bound I got uses the fact that $\mathrm{sech}(ax) \geq e^{-a^2 x^2/2}$. Working through the algebra, you will obtain
$$
f(a) \geq \sqrt{\frac{1}{1 + a^2}} . 
$$
Are there better upper and lower bounds for this integral?

Comment: Look at equation $(9)$ in  https://mdpi-res.com/d_attachment/axioms/axioms-10-00308/article_deploy/axioms-10-00308.pdf

Answer (score 0):

$$f(a) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}  \text{sech}(a x)\,\,e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} \, dx=\frac{1}{a\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}  \text{sech}(y)\,\,e^{-\frac{y^2}{2 a^2}}\,dy$$
Using
$$ \text{sech}(y) < \frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{y^2}{3}\right)^{3/2}}$$ we have
$$a\,f(a) < \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\,\, U\left(\frac{1}{2},0,\frac{3}{2 a^2}\right) $$ where appears Tricomi's confluent hypergeometric function. This can also write in terms of Bessel functions
$$a\,f(a) < \frac{3}{2} \sqrt{\frac{3}{2 \pi }}\frac 1{a^2}e^{\frac{3}{4 a^2}} \left(K_1\left(\frac{3}{4 a^2}\right)-K_0\left(\frac{3}{4 a^2}\right)\right)$$
Just a few numbers
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
a & a\,f(a) & \text{upper bound} \\
 1 & 0.74126 & 0.74384 \\
 2 & 1.01374 & 1.03235 \\
 3 & 1.12100 & 1.15955 \\
 4 & 1.17114 & 1.22666 \\
 5 & 1.19788 & 1.26662 \\
 6 & 1.21361 & 1.29247 \\
 7 & 1.22357 & 1.31024 \\
 8 & 1.23024 & 1.32302 \\
 9 & 1.23491 & 1.33255 \\
 10 & 1.23831 & 1.33986
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

If we make
$$ \text{sech}(y) \sim {\left(1+\frac{y^2}{b}\right)^{-c}}$$
for suitable $(b,c)$
$$a\,f(a) \sim \sqrt{\frac{b}{2}}\,\,U\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2}-c,\frac{b}{2 a^2}\right)$$
Minimizing
$$\Phi(b,c)=\int_0^\infty \Bigg[\text{sech}(y) - {\left(1+\frac{y^2}{b}\right)^{-c}}\Bigg]^2 \,dy$$ making $b,c$ rational lead to
$$b=\frac{659}{143} \qquad \qquad c=\frac{69}{32}\qquad \qquad  \Phi_{\text{min}}=1.42\times 10^{-4}$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
a & a\, f(a) & \text{approximation} & \Delta \\
 1 & 0.74126 & 0.74431 & 0.00304 \\
 2 & 1.01374 & 1.01575 & 0.00201 \\
 3 & 1.12100 & 1.12392 & 0.00291 \\
 4 & 1.17114 & 1.17608 & 0.00494 \\
 5 & 1.19788 & 1.20488 & 0.00699 \\
 6 & 1.21361 & 1.22236 & 0.00875 \\
 7 & 1.22357 & 1.23373 & 0.01016 \\
 8 & 1.23024 & 1.24153 & 0.01130 \\
  9 & 1.23491 & 1.24711 & 0.01220 \\
 10 & 1.23831 & 1.25123 & 0.01292
\end{array}
\right)$$